# More than 5 close votes?

Tags: bug, status-completed, closed-questions, vote-to-close

I voted to close this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17482385/replace-all-occurrences-of-string-only-if-they-dont-start-by). It has been closed with the following reasons:

> "Questions asking for code must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the *expected* results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)" – chue x, Avadhani Y, Luv, dandan78
>
> "Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it *should* work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)" – Jack, Stony, Xenph Yan, Grijesh Chauhan

You will note that there are two close vote reasons, and eight names there. I've read that a question can have more than 5 close votes if it is closed, re-openened, and then closed. Is this what happened here, or is this a bug, or possibly a new feature?

Comment: My guess is that some of those users cast a close vote early on which then expired before the question was actually closed, but it's hard to say for certain. The question was only closed once, though.

Comment: @TimStone - why would expired votes count towards the close tally?

Comment: I'm not sure, I would expect that to be a bug like you indicated, though the fact that this has been retagged as support suggests otherwise.

Comment: @m0sa -- why was this untagged as a bug?

Comment: it seemed more of a "why did this happen" than "this shouldn't have happened" question

Comment: @m0sa I am not sure about that. If the OP tagged it [meta-tag:bug] he probably thought it was a bug. I am retagging... (sorry)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems the first 3 close votes were invalidated by a scheduled task

[image]

after reviewers decided to leave the question open:

[image]

The scheduled task invalidates votes that are more than 4 days old, and were dismissed by a "leave open" review result. That explains why the close flag with the *very 1337* time-stamp `2013-07-05 13:37:10` survived. The question was closed only after dandan78 voted to close the question as his was the 5th valid close vote. Only the 5 names that issued helpful votes are listed:

[image]

### Update

A fix for the display issue where aged (invalidated) close votes are showing up in the explanatory section is being pushed out in the next few hours.

Comment: Didn't "leave open" just kick the question out of the review queue? Starting from when does it also invalidate the votes?

Comment: I guess I'll ask a similar question that I asked @TimStone - why would invalidated votes count towards the close tally?

Comment: Right, this part makes sense. It's why the invalidated votes were used in the "The users who voted to close gave these specific reasons:" section. They should have presumably been excluded.

Comment: @TimStone it doesn't state that all the votes listed below were taken into account when closing the question, though

Comment: That's an extreme technicality, I don't think this is the intuitive behaviour.

Comment: I have to agree with @TimStone, it is not intuitive.

Comment: @m0sa - In any case, if you can confirm that the non-intuitive behavior is either a bug or is status-by-design, I will accept your answer. Thanks for doing the research!

Comment: It's a bug - invalidated votes don't count toward closing, so they shouldn't contribute toward the reasons display when closed either.